# Strange MySQL performance behavior

Tags: mysql, performance

My question will be long so I try to be brief. I'm trying to optimize a query in MySQL and I wrote two versions of it. These two return the exact same results (as in the number of rows and columns and content). But these two differ in execution time a lot. The strange part is that when I print their `explain` they seem almost the same, one might even say the slower one should be more performant! Here they are:

---

### The query version **A**:

Average execution time: **0.0846 sec**

SQL:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS SQL_NO_CACHE
    a.account_id
    , MAX(mc_cp.phone_number) AS phone_number
FROM account a
INNER JOIN entity_revision er ON (a.entity_id = er.entity_id AND a.account_id = er.revision_id)
LEFT JOIN contact mc ON (a.contact_entity_id = mc.entity_id)
LEFT JOIN entity_revision mc_er ON (mc.entity_id = mc_er.entity_id AND mc.contact_id = mc_er.revision_id AND mc_er.state = 0)
LEFT JOIN contact_phone mc_cp ON (mc.contact_id = mc_cp.contact_id)
LEFT JOIN contact_email mc_ce ON (mc.contact_id = mc_ce.contact_id)
LEFT JOIN contact_website mc_cw ON (mc.contact_id = mc_cw.contact_id)
LEFT JOIN contact_address mc_ca ON (mc.contact_id = mc_ca.contact_id)
WHERE
    er.state = 0
AND
    a.type IN (1)
AND
(
        a.account_id IN
        (
            SELECT ac.account_id
            FROM account_contact ac
            INNER JOIN contact c ON (ac.contact_entity_id = c.entity_id)
            INNER JOIN entity_revision er ON (c.entity_id = er.entity_id AND c.contact_id = er.revision_id)
            LEFT JOIN contact_phone cp ON (c.contact_id = cp.contact_id)
            LEFT JOIN contact_email ce ON (c.contact_id = ce.contact_id)
            LEFT JOIN contact_website cw ON (c.contact_id = cw.contact_id)
            WHERE er.state = 0
        )
    OR
        a.contact_entity_id IN
        (
            SELECT c.entity_id
            FROM contact c
            INNER JOIN entity_revision er ON (c.entity_id = er.entity_id AND c.contact_id = er.revision_id)
            LEFT JOIN contact_phone cp ON (c.contact_id = cp.contact_id)
            LEFT JOIN contact_email ce ON (c.contact_id = ce.contact_id)
            LEFT JOIN contact_website cw ON (c.contact_id = cw.contact_id)
            WHERE er.state = 0
        )
)
GROUP BY a.account_id
ORDER BY name ASC
LIMIT 0, 75
```

`explain` output:

```
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type   | possible_keys                                                  | key               | key_len | ref                                           | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | a     | ref    | PRIMARY,inxName,inx_entity_id,fk_account_contact1_idx,inx_type | inx_type          | 1       | const                                         | 1361 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | mc    | ref    | inx_entity_id                                                  | inx_entity_id     | 4       | db.a.contact_entity_id                        |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | er    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                        | PRIMARY           | 9       | db.a.entity_id,db.a.account_id,const          |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | mc_er | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                        | PRIMARY           | 9       | db.mc.entity_id,db.mc.contact_id,const        |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | mc_cp | ref    | Relationship1_idx                                              | Relationship1_idx | 4       | db.mc.contact_id                              |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | mc_ce | ref    | Relationship1_idx                                              | Relationship1_idx | 4       | db.mc.contact_id                              |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | mc_cw | ref    | Relationship1_idx                                              | Relationship1_idx | 4       | db.mc.contact_id                              |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | mc_ca | ref    | Relationship1_idx                                              | Relationship1_idx | 4       | db.mc.contact_id                              |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | c     | ref    | PRIMARY,inx_entity_id                                          | inx_entity_id     | 4       | func                                          |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | er    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                        | PRIMARY           | 9       | func,db.c.contact_id,const                    |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | cp    | ref    | Relationship1_idx                                              | Relationship1_idx | 4       | db.c.contact_id                               |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ce    | ref    | Relationship1_idx                                              | Relationship1_idx | 4       | db.c.contact_id                               |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | cw    | ref    | Relationship1_idx                                              | Relationship1_idx | 4       | db.c.contact_id                               |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ac    | ref    | PRIMARY,fk_account_contact1,fk_account_contact_account1_idx    | PRIMARY           | 4       | func                                          |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | c     | ref    | PRIMARY,inx_entity_id                                          | inx_entity_id     | 4       | db.ac.contact_entity_id                       |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | er    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                        | PRIMARY           | 9       | db.ac.contact_entity_id,db.c.contact_id,const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | cp    | ref    | Relationship1_idx                                              | Relationship1_idx | 4       | db.c.contact_id                               |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ce    | ref    | Relationship1_idx                                              | Relationship1_idx | 4       | db.c.contact_id                               |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | cw    | ref    | Relationship1_idx                                              | Relationship1_idx | 4       | db.c.contact_id                               |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
19 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

---

### The query version **B**:

Average execution time: **0.32078 sec**

SQL:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS SQL_NO_CACHE
    a.account_id
    , MAX(IF(mc_cp.phone_number) AS phone_number
FROM account a
INNER JOIN entity_revision er ON (a.entity_id = er.entity_id AND a.account_id = er.revision_id)
LEFT JOIN contact mc ON (a.contact_entity_id = mc.entity_id)
LEFT JOIN entity_revision mc_er ON (mc.entity_id = mc_er.entity_id AND mc.contact_id = mc_er.revision_id AND mc_er.state = 0)
LEFT JOIN contact_phone mc_cp ON (mc.contact_id = mc_cp.contact_id)
LEFT JOIN contact_email mc_ce ON (mc.contact_id = mc_ce.contact_id)
LEFT JOIN contact_website mc_cw ON (mc.contact_id = mc_cw.contact_id)
LEFT JOIN contact_address mc_ca ON (mc.contact_id = mc_ca.contact_id)

LEFT JOIN contact smc ON (a.contact_entity_id = smc.entity_id)
LEFT JOIN entity_revision smc_er ON (smc.entity_id = smc_er.entity_id AND smc.contact_id = smc_er.revision_id AND smc_er.state = 0)
LEFT JOIN contact_phone smc_cp ON (smc.contact_id = smc_cp.contact_id)
LEFT JOIN contact_email smc_ce ON (smc.contact_id = smc_ce.contact_id)
LEFT JOIN contact_website smc_cw ON (smc.contact_id = smc_cw.contact_id)
LEFT JOIN contact_address smc_ca ON (smc.contact_id = smc_ca.contact_id)

LEFT JOIN account_contact sac ON (a.account_id = sac.account_id)
LEFT JOIN contact sc ON (sac.contact_entity_id = sc.entity_id)
LEFT JOIN entity_revision ser ON (sc.entity_id = ser.entity_id AND sc.contact_id = ser.revision_id AND ser.state = 0)
LEFT JOIN contact_phone scp ON (sc.contact_id = scp.contact_id)
LEFT JOIN contact_email sce ON (sc.contact_id = sce.contact_id)
LEFT JOIN contact_website scw ON (sc.contact_id = scw.contact_id)

WHERE
    er.state = 0
AND
    a.type IN (1)
GROUP BY a.account_id
ORDER BY name ASC
LIMIT 0, 75
```

`explain` output:

```
+----+-------------+--------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type   | possible_keys                                                  | key               | key_len | ref                                      | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a      | ref    | PRIMARY,inxName,inx_entity_id,fk_account_contact1_idx,inx_type | inx_type          | 1       | const                                    | 1361 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mc     | ref    | inx_entity_id                                                  | inx_entity_id     | 4       | db.a.contact_entity_id                   |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | er     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                        | PRIMARY           | 9       | db.a.entity_id,db.a.account_id,const     |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mc_er  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                        | PRIMARY           | 9       | db.mc.entity_id,db.mc.contact_id,const   |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mc_cp  | ref    | Relationship1_idx                                              | Relationship1_idx | 4       | db.mc.contact_id                         |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mc_ce  | ref    | Relationship1_idx                                              | Relationship1_idx | 4       | db.mc.contact_id                         |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mc_cw  | ref    | Relationship1_idx                                              | Relationship1_idx | 4       | db.mc.contact_id                         |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mc_ca  | ref    | Relationship1_idx                                              | Relationship1_idx | 4       | db.mc.contact_id                         |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | smc    | ref    | inx_entity_id                                                  | inx_entity_id     | 4       | db.a.contact_entity_id                   |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | smc_er | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                        | PRIMARY           | 9       | db.smc.entity_id,db.smc.contact_id,const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | smc_cp | ref    | Relationship1_idx                                              | Relationship1_idx | 4       | db.smc.contact_id                        |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | smc_ce | ref    | Relationship1_idx                                              | Relationship1_idx | 4       | db.smc.contact_id                        |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | smc_cw | ref    | Relationship1_idx                                              | Relationship1_idx | 4       | db.smc.contact_id                        |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | smc_ca | ref    | Relationship1_idx                                              | Relationship1_idx | 4       | db.smc.contact_id                        |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sac    | ref    | PRIMARY,fk_account_contact_account1_idx                        | PRIMARY           | 4       | db.a.account_id                          |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sc     | ref    | inx_entity_id                                                  | inx_entity_id     | 4       | db.sac.contact_entity_id                 |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ser    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                        | PRIMARY           | 9       | db.sc.entity_id,db.sc.contact_id,const   |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | scp    | ref    | Relationship1_idx                                              | Relationship1_idx | 4       | db.sc.contact_id                         |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sce    | ref    | Relationship1_idx                                              | Relationship1_idx | 4       | db.sc.contact_id                         |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | scw    | ref    | Relationship1_idx                                              | Relationship1_idx | 4       | db.sc.contact_id                         |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+--------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
20 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Isn't it strange? Am I missing something?

Comment: More joins means longer query execution time, especially if you have a lot of NULL rows on the right sides of those left outer joins. Also, unless I'm mistaken the non-correlated subqueries in the where clause of your first query are evaluated once and the results cached, so you're not taking much of a hit there performance-wise.

Comment: Shouldn't it somehow show in the `explain`?

Comment: Both of your queries have many flaws. First, even thought MySQL allows you to mix aggregate operators with columns that were not grouped by, you shouldn't do it. To avoid this you can isolate the query that requires the group by and join it to the rest of the statement. Even in your first query, you seem to have many unecessary joins, especially in the `IN` clauses.

Comment: @plalx Thanks for the input. In my experience, moving a join into a sub-query (in from section) should be a last resort because MySQL does not incorporate indices for sub-query results' and thus having a sub-query which returns a lot of rows will result in a poor performance. Nevertheless, this is not my question. I'm just surprised why the performance difference of the two is not shown in the `explain`! Or at least I can not see it.

Comment: @plalx BTW, none of the joins are unnecessary. I've just simplified the `SQL`s to compress the question. The joins are there so I can use the tables in `where` clause. I just didn't mention the conditions here because they have no influence on the question asked. But thanks for being precise.